# Reuse Test Cases for Different URLs

Tags: python, selenium, url, python-unittest

I am creating test cases on menu that may be same across all web pages.

So I want to reuse the test cases for different urls. I don't want to create a new test case for every url. It will make a test suite cumbersome.

I am using automated tests with Python's unittest and Selenium.

Comment: The test case for testing your menu should be in its own test method only. As you want to repeat that test on every page, you will get all your tests fail when the menu test fails - then you cannot tell where is the root cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a parameter for the URL.
Maybe using environment parameters:
https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables

or something else depending on your test framework

Comment: BaseUrl=os.environ['base_url'] driver.get(BaseUrl') before running script set base URL environment variable.